# how to refesh Fragment using addOnPageChangerListner?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello i use below code to switch between fragments.
I noticed that fragments are not refreshed when i scoll them.
How to make my fragmets update each time i scoll to next fragment.

anyidea? thank you

```
private  void initViewPager()
    {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        listFragments.add(new FragmentA());
        listFragments.add(new FragmentB());
        //if(fav == true)
        listFragments.add(new FragmentC());

        PagerAdapter myPageAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(),listFragments);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(myPageAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener());


    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int selectedItem)
    {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(selectedItem);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {
        int selectedItem = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
        itemTag = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(selectedItem);
        HorizontalScrollView hScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.h_scroll_view);
        View tabView = mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
        int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (hScrollView.getWidth()-tabView.getWidth() * 2);
        hScrollView.smoothScrollTo(scrollPos,0);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better create class `BaseFragment extends Fragment`, add custom void etc. `public void updateFragment()` and other fragments etc. FragmentA,FragmentB,FragmentC extend from `BaseFragment`

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment { 
     public void updateFragment(){
     }
 }

public class FragmentA extends BaseFragment { 
   @Override
   public void updateFragment(){
     //start my job
   }
}
```

Then in `addOnPageChangerListner` you can update fragment `listFragments.get(selectedItem).updateFragment;`